# Solving the Recurrence: $P(A_{n,r})=(1-\frac{r}{n+1})\cdot P(A_{n-1,r}) + (\frac{r-1}{n+1})\cdot P(A_{n-1,r-1})$ $\ \ $(Pólya’s urns)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recurrence-relations

$P(A_{n,r})=(1-\frac{r}{n+1})\cdot P(A_{n-1,r}) + (\frac{r-1}{n+1})\cdot P(A_{n-1,r-1})$   $\ \ $($P(A_{0,1})=1$)

I encountered the recurrence above in a text on basic probability theory, analyzing Pólya’s urns. The equation is describing the event of having $r$  red balls in the urn at time $n$.

The authors then solve the recurence by defining $q_{n,r}=P(A_{n,r})\cdot (n+1)!$ and then arriving at the (immediate?) conclusion that $q_{n,r}=n!$ and then that $P(A_{n,r})=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Would someone care to explain how one arrives at these conclusions?

Comment: You need a bigger base case, because right now many inputs are not well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to provide the text in question, or at least more context so we can help formulate the problem.

That said, I assume you understand how the recursion is derived and the issue is more with the change of variable. It looks like the correct from should be $q_{n,r} = n!$ rather than $\frac{1}{n!}$? You can prove that $q$ is such using an induction argument over the recursion and then the probability result drops straight out (or you could just do the induction over $P(A_{n,r})$ without the change of variable)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The original text is not in English and translating the whole thing would take a while. Either way, I do indeed understand the derivation and the problem was with the change of variable. Would you care to explain what such an inductive argument would look like? (And it seems you are right, it should in fact be $q_{n,r}=n!$)

Comment: How familiar are you with using induction? You provided the base case for n=0 (probability is 1 if r=1, 0 otherwise). It just remains to show that the form provided for q or P satisfies the recursion identity. Try plugging it in and hopefully you can convince yourself it works.